# Pandas.apply returning random substrings

Tags: python, pandas

pandas.apply function returning random substrings instead of full string

I've already tried:

```
def extract_ticker(title):
    for word in title:
        word_str = word.encode('utf-8')
        if word_str in constituents['Symbol'].values:
            return word_str
sp500news3['tickers'] = sp500news3['title'].apply(extract_ticker)
```

which returns

```
sp500news3['tickers'] 

79944        M
181781       M
213175       C
93554        C
257327       T
```

instead of expected output

```
79944        MSFT
181781       WMB
213175       CSX
93554        C
257327       TWX
```

Create sample from below

```
constituents =  pd.DataFrame({"Symbol":["TWX","C","MSFT","WMB"]})

sp500news3 = pd.DataFrame({"title":["MSFT Vista corporate sales go very well","WMB No Anglican consensus on Episcopal Church","CSX quarterly profit rises",'C says 30 bln capital helps exceed target','TWX plans cable spinoff']})
```

Comment: A string is treated as a list of characters when you loop through the `title`. You should tokenize the string first or start with a simple `title.split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with joined values with word bondaries and `|`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in constituents['Symbol'])

sp500news3['tickers'] = sp500news3['title'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (sp500news3)
                                           title tickers
0        MSFT Vista corporate sales go very well    MSFT
1  WMB No Anglican consensus on Episcopal Church     WMB
2                     CSX quarterly profit rises     NaN
3      C says 30 bln capital helps exceed target       C
4                        TWX plans cable spinoff     TWX
```

Your solution should working with `split` by whitespaces, maybe `encode` is necessary remove too:

```
def extract_ticker(title):
    for word in title.split():
        word_str = word
        if word_str in constituents['Symbol'].values:
            return word_str

sp500news3['tickers'] = sp500news3['title'].apply(extract_ticker)
print (sp500news3)
                                           title tickers
0        MSFT Vista corporate sales go very well    MSFT
1  WMB No Anglican consensus on Episcopal Church     WMB
2                     CSX quarterly profit rises    None
3      C says 30 bln capital helps exceed target       C
4                        TWX plans cable spinoff     TWX
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expression extraction of the ticker instead?

```
tickers = ('TWX', 'C', 'MSFT', 'WMB')
regex = '({})'.format('|'.join(tickers))

sp500news3['tickers'] = sp500news3['title'].str.extract(regex)
```